# Classifying Singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

This is my first post here. I'm working on a complex analysis questions, where I am asked to find and classify all of the the singularities of a given function. My function is as follows:

$$f(z) = \frac{z^3+1}{z^2(z+1)}$$

If I'm not mistaken, by setting the denominator equal to $0$, it trivially yields that $0$ (multiplicity $2$) and $-1$ (simple) are the singularities. Is the order of the singularity simply equal to the multiplicity? I have an upcoming exam and I want to fully understand this. I've seen many posts about Laurent Expansions, but I don't quite understand them.

Any help would be wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: You need to check what kind of singularities they are (ie. removable, pole, or essential). Think of what happens when you write out a power series at $z=-1$.

Comment: We have only discussed poles at this point in my course, so I would assume that these are pole singularities.

Comment: Are you sure you have not discussed removable singularities? These are the equivalent of removable discontinuities for a function of one real variable.

Comment: Ah yes. I overlooked something simple in my notes. Thank you!